# Android : FragmentPagerAdapter don't saved the state of Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, fragmentpageradapter

I have a problem with the FragmentPagerAdapter .

I can not save the state of the Fragment and then there is the view that within the Fragment . Whenever I use the swipe left and right , the Fragment is recreated by overriding the method getItem ( int position ) in the static class that extends the FragmentPagerAdapter .

```
 public static class GraphicsCollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int NUM_ITEMS = 3; // number of tabs

    public GraphicsCollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

        super(fm);
        fragmentList = new AnalyzeFragmentPageListWithDate();
        fragment1 = new  AnalyzeFragmentPage1();
        fragment2 = new  AnalyzeFragmentPage2();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "getItem() -> New fragment at position " + position);


        switch (position) {

        case 0:         
            return fragmentList;
       case 1:
            return fragment1;
       case 2:
             return fragment2;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {

         case 0:
            return "Fragm1";
        case 1:
            return "Fragm2";
        case 2:
            return "Fragm3";

    }
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }


}
```

Within the method OnCreateView of each instance of the Fragment there are several steps to the SQLite database and this causes a saturation of the Database Connection Pool.

The warning found whenever change dynamically fragment is: "W / SQLiteConnectionPool (1111 ) : A SQLiteConnection object for database ' / data / data / com.myapp / databases / mydb ' was leaked ! Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database When it is no longer needed . "

I already tried to use the FragmentStatePagerAdapter without success.

Could you kindly tell me how to proceed ? I do not want the Fragment is regenerated each time, causing problems to the database. Have you got an example for save Fragment/View sate?

I have not found any suggestion for now .
thank you very much

Comment: Do you have listviews in your fragments ?

Comment: I have listviews and bar graphs. Thanks

Comment: I had similar issues where the listview in the first fragment  reloads after coming from the third fragment.What i did was ,i replaced Fragment with listFragment and used a SimpleCursorAdapter and LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> to populate the listview

Comment: can you give me an example of this fix? Thanks

Comment: Its a good link http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html

Comment: How do you call GraphicsCollectionPagerAdapter ?

Answer (score 8):

use setOffscreenPageLimit property for your ViewPager object.

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerId);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a new instance of `Fragment` every time the `getItem()` is called

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:         
        return new FragmentList();
    case 1:
        return new  AnalyzeFragmentPage1();
    case 2:
         return new  AnalyzeFragmentPage2();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that `FragmentPagerAdapter` does not work exactly like normal `Adapter` meaning it does NOT use an empty vessel `Fragment` and then refills it with different data.

Instead it creates a new `Fragment` whenever it is needed. So you should pass data (if any) when the `Fragment` is created. Please study the [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) in the Android docs.

In a real time projects instead of passing current position to a new `Fragment` you could pass the actual `ID` of the entry that a `Fragment` should refer to.